# Dreamweaver form button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, dreamweaver

I've been struggling with this one for some time. I have this code:

```
<h2 id="registerH2">Subscribe to the cake club.<br>
 Please fill out the form. (* means required)</h2>
<div id="subscribeBox">
    <form class="subscribeForm" name="Subscription Form"><br>
        <input Name="First Name" type="text" required id="fname" placeholder="First  Name*"><br><br>
        <input id="lname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name*" name="Last Name" required><br><br>
        <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email*" name="Email" required><br><br>
        <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Address (optional)" name="Address"><br><br>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send" onclick="href=registered.html">
    </form>
</div>
```

So what I want to do is when I click the "send" button in my website, to direct me to another html file I have. Right now it's not working with this code.

(This is for my assignment I'm not working on a cake club :D)

Comment: Do not forgert to remove ```onclick=''href="registered.html"``` it is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your want is a `action="registered.html"` attribute in your form

In any form when you hit a `submit` type `input`

`<form action="registered.html"> [...] </form>` is triggered

read more on w3school
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct your html:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send" onclick="window.location.href=registered.html">
```

Though I think you should do it in the form tag, no need to use javascript here

```
<form action='registered.php' method='post'>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just added a single quote:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send"    onclick="window.location.href='registered.html'">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use anchor tag for that, if redirection is the only purpose.

```
 <a href="register.html">
       <button>Send</button>
</a>
```